# Confused: Help Understanding Passport.js authenticate User

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am following a [Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-authentication-using-passportjs-and-passport-local-mongoose/) tutorial on using passport Js passport-local-mongoose.

There are a few thing i am confused about. Which I am not understanding. In order to register a user you use a post request like so:

```
router.post("/register", function (req, res) {
    User.register(new User({ email: req.body.email, username: req.body.username }), req.body.password, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: "Your account could not be saved. Error: " + err });
        }
        else {
            req.login(user, (er) => {
                if (er) {
                    res.json({ success: false, message: er });
                }
                else {
                    res.json({ success: true, message: "Your account has been saved" });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here I understand that you get the email, username and password from a form. After you get it you input it into your DB.

The part I am having a hard time understanding is the login. From my understanding to login, you need to check if the user exists or if there are any errors in the form. Such as email or password. The tutorial has the following code:

```
router.post("/login", function (req, res) {
    if (!req.body.username) {
        res.json({ success: false, message: "Username was not given" })
    }
    else if (!req.body.password) {
        res.json({ success: false, message: "Password was not given" })
    }
    else {
        passport.authenticate("local", function (err, user, info) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({ success: false, message: err });
            }
            else {
                if (!user) {
                    res.json({ success: false, message: "username or password incorrect" });
                }
                else {
                    const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id, username: user.username }, secretkey, { expiresIn: "24h" });
                    res.json({ success: true, message: "Authentication successful", token: token });
                }
            }
        })(req, res);
    }
});
```

This is where i get really confused. In the register we needed to get the user input from the form. For example username, email and password. But in the login this does not seem to be the case. You use :

```
passport.authenticate("local", function (err, user, info)
```

It seems that this `user` has all the information from my form.Such as username, email and password.But when did this information get put into `user`. How does passport know what `user` is.I never passed in the req information from the form like i did with register. I was expecting to do something like:

```
   passport.authenticate("local", function (err, req.body.email, req.body.password, info)
```

Where is this `user` object created? Was is stored after I registered the user? From my understanding, I would of thought we needed to pass in the form data `req.body.username, req.body.email, req.body.password` into `passport.authenticate()`. I checked the passport doc and I didn't find anything regarding `user`. Are there any docs out there that explain this? Passport seems a little confusing to use and very little documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By coincidence I am learning the same thing right now, and had the exact same question (so the caveat here is that I am by no means an expert, but hopefully this can help).

It seems that the form is actually being processed by your LocalStrategy that isn't in your post, but hopefully you have set up too.

LocalStrategy processes your form data and expects there to be a req.body.username and req.body.password which it accesses by default.

Something like this

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function (username, password, done) {

    db.users.findByUsername(username, (err, user) => {

      if(err) return done(err);
 

      if(!user) return done(null, false);
 

      if(user.password != password) return done(null, false);
 
      return done(null, user)
    });
  })
);
```

In this case the anonymous function is actually being called with (req.body, username, req.body.password, done)

You can also overwrite those values if your body will have different properties by passing an object before the anonymous function.

Something like this

```
{
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'oneTimePassword'
}
```

What I would be interested in, and maybe someone can comment, is can we tell LocalStrategy to look elsewhere for the username and password arguments? For example req.email instead of req.body.email (If I want to attach it there after validation or something)